# SQL Server stored procedure import Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

As stated in the title i am not able to import an excell from a stored procedure.

If I try manually all gone right but if I run stored procedure I get privilege issue :

> SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

That is the command I run in the stored procedure :

```
set @str_command = 'SELECT * INTO Import FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @str_path + ''',[Sheet1$])' ;
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @str_command;
```

I do not understand why all gone fine if i run manually (GUI) but from stored procedure i get that error, does the GUI use different commands ?

UPDATE : 
The excel that i need to import is a 97-2003 version

Comment: What does it mean `manually/from GUI`? SSMS/client application?

Comment: @lad2025 : yes when i say GUI i mean SSMS

Comment: @Ralph no i am working on my local machine, i had only SSMS and my SQLExpress running

Comment: Have you checked your permissions to use OpenRowSet? `SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS')`

Comment: @Ralph thanks for help, no i have check it now and return to me '1' as result

Comment: Have a look at the following website and go through the list to ensure that you have met all prerequisites: http://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm Also note the differences for the various Excel Versions as well as SQL Server Versions (x86 or x64). So you might want to include your server version in the question as well.

Comment: I have been able to replicate the problem with multiple installations of SQL Server (2008R2 and 2012 and 2016) with Office 2010 / Office 2016. But I have been able to resolve the problem again with the above references website and by eliminating all but one installation of SQL Server.